# Creating Drill Down / Master detail navigation/Lookup screen in PowerApps Portal

Tags: powerapps-portal

## Problem Statement

We need to create a Drill Down Workflow of screens in **PowerApp Portal application** where the user can drill down from Parent List to it's child list and so on.

> **For Example:**
>
> > -The First screen should list the Phone Brands.
> >     -On clicking any brand->it should bring up a list of Phone Models of that Brand.
> >     -On clicking any phone model, it should bring up the hardware configuration of that phone.

## Query:

We have been able add Lists to Child Pages and navigate between pages using the Target type attributes of a List but, **we haven't been able to pass the Filter condition from parent screen to child screen** 
i.e. when the user cliks to drill down from Brands to Models screen.

> > This results in the Models screen showing Phone models from all brands.

It it simple to achieve the same using **PowerApp Canvas** application but, we are **struggling** to achieve the same using **Power Apps Portal** application.

**>>Would appreciate inputs to achieve the same using Power App POrtal Application**

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add some query parameter when someone clicks on a brand name in the parent page on the portal and when the user is taken to the child page (model level), there you can read the query parameter to filter.

For readingg query paramter in liquid - https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/configuration-guide/liquid-templates/objects/request/

For adding query parameter on brand click- basic js/jquery should be ok.

Comment: Thanks! Shamefully.. am a novice on PowerApps Portal and do not currently know how to add Query Paramaters on Brand Form and read it on Model Page and finally filter the Model list to show the filtered records. _Would request some sample code /hand holding / Screen Shots to get us through_